# Extract text between V="..." Ruby

Tags: ruby

Ok instead of printing the whole line:

```
<von_icd_code V="A00"/>
```

I only would like to extract the text between V="..", in this case A00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [**`Nokogiri::XML::Document`**](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/HTML/Document.html)

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML::Document.parse('<von_icd_code V="A00"/>')
doc.at("von_icd_code")["V"] # => "A00"
```

Answer (score 2):

`scan` is the wrong method if you are interested only in a single occurrence. There must also, in general, be a check that the substring was found *at all*.

The code should look like this

```
s = '<von_icd_code V="A00"/>'

if s =~ /V="([^"]*)"/
  puts $~[1]
end
```

**output**

```
A00
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
'<von_icd_code V="A00"/>'.scan(/V="(.+)"/)[0][0]
=> "A00"
```